# How to change data type and remove column from table in fuelphp?

Tags: mysql, fuelphp

I want to change varchar to text and remove remark column in shops table.  How can I migrate this in fuelphp

I create Old migration file: `004_create_shops.php`

```
'address' => array('constraint' => 300, 'type' => 'varchar'),
'remarks' => array('constraint' => 200, 'type' => 'varchar'),
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is under heavy development (which means this is a relatively new migration which is not commited into any VCS) then you can simply delete that row from the migration and delete the column from the database using a client with a GUI. From console:

`ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN remarks;`

If this file has been added to your VCS then you shouldn't edit this file directly anymore. The history should remain consistent. If somebody checks out an older version, he/she might get into trouble.

You should add a new migration. Make sure to fill both the up and the down part with correct code.

Up:

`\DBUtil::drop_fields('my_table', 'remarks');`

Down:

```
\DBUtil::add_fields('my_table', array(
    'remarks' => array('constraint' => 200, 'type' => 'varchar'),
));
```

Adding a down part is required so your database remains consistent when migrating up or down.

You will have to do the same with type changing:

- Change the type in the up part (use `\DBUtil::modify_fields`, it has the same method signature as `\DBUtil::add_fields`)
- Change the type back to the original to preserve consistency

You can check the documentation [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/dbutil.htm)